# is it possible to use push() to add element into observable array

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, observable

I created an `Observable` array of type `string`. like below

```js
products: Observable<string[]>;
```

I want to push some elements into `products array`. I don't want to use subscribe methods here. it is not allowing me to use the normal push method. see below code

```js
this.products.push("mova");
```

what is the alternative for the above code(push element to an array)? tell me one simple way to do it. Please don't use any dependency injection here to perform the next() and subscribe().

Comment: not sure, what you want to do, but take a look at [Subjects](https://rxjs.dev/guide/subject)

Comment: just create observable array and push elements into it. don't use any other service or component just do it in same component where you created your array

Comment: An observable of an array isn't itself an array, and doesn't otherwise have a push method. Either you need to get the array (e.g. by subscribing) _then_ push to it or send out a new array with the additional values. There's not enough context here to be more specific.

Comment: there is nothing I want know other than this @jonrsharpe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't push to the property which is an ***Observable*** of `string[]` because it is expected that it will have a stream of data which will set the values in future.

What you can do is:

```
products: Observable<string[]>;
items: string[] = [];

// push the values in it.

this.products = of(items); // <--it will set the observables of string[]
```

Still you need to subscribe to the products observables to get the data.